# HTML tags are not showing after rendering in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates

I am learning django and think to make a site as a practical so i am on it. but got a problem with `<textarea>` tag in html.

clearly, i have `<textarea>` on my webpage that is user input area for long text and i am storing that given input in database that contains some HTML tags like `<div>, <span>, <body>` as a web artical, and when it render with template the autoescape applying and all tags like `<div>, <span>, <body>` are showing as normal word because of security issue. 
and When i am using safe filter then all the HTML tags can't be print on webpage that is i can not print `<b>` or `<em>` on webpage.

But i want some html tags like `<b></b>, <em></em>, <code></code>, <li></li>` to be render as user need, i mean when a writer writing an artical about HTML then he can write `<b></b>` in his artical as normal word but when he need to bold some word he can use `<b></b>` HTML tag for this as well.

Comment: So what is it exactly that you're asking? Do you want to strip out some HTML tags but not others? Are the tags included in the HTML you're displaying rendering as escaped text? What have you tried to resolve the problem? I would suggest adding some additional details and code examples, otherwise this question will probably be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [django-html_sanitizer](https://github.com/ui/django-html_sanitizer) app. After adding it to your project you can use it to remove/escape all tags, except those that you choose to leave.

Example usage in a template:

```
{% strip_html your_text "em, b, code, li" %}
```